# Can't insert data into mysql database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Answer always "terjadi kesalahan saat mengirim komen!". Can anyone help me?

```
$message = mysql_real_escape_string(bbcode_to_html($message));
if (mysql_query('insert into topics (id_parent, id, id_user, title, message, id_author, timestamp, timestamp_user) select "' . $dn1['id_parent'] . '", "' . $id . '", max(id_user)+1, "", "' . $message . '", "' . $_SESSION['userid'] . '", "' . time() . '", "' . time() . '" from topics where id="' . $id . '"') and mysql_query('update topics set timestamp_user="' . time() . '" where id="' . $id . '" and id_user=1')){
    ?><header class="major">
    Komen sukses! Kembali ke <a href="read_topic.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">Topik!</a>
</header>
<?php
}else{
    echo 'Terjadi kesalahan saat mengirim komen!';
}
```

Comment: Echo the generated SQL and run it yourself in PHPMyAdmin or terminal and the error message you receive back will help to identify why it failed.

Comment: it probably means you do not even open the connection to the database...

Comment: i don't get error message, i only get message "Terjadi kesalahan saat mengirim komen!", i use notepad++, what i should do ?

Comment: i has open my connection, before this i give this code

Comment: $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
       mysql_select_db("klimaks",$connection);

Comment: Try separating the query into a separate variable (`$sql`) so you can echo it to the screen. Perhaps there is an error in it? I expect it has a SQL injection vulnerability in it, in any case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited:

Try just adding this code:

```
<?php
$message = mysql_real_escape_string(bbcode_to_html($message));

$sqlquery1 = 'insert into topics (id_parent, id, id_user, title, message, id_author, timestamp, timestamp_user) select "' . $dn1['id_parent'] . '", "' . $id . '", max(id_user)+1, "", "' . $message . '", "' . $_SESSION['userid'] . '", "' . time() . '", "' . time() . '" from topics where id="' . $id . '"';

$sqlquery2 = 'update topics set timestamp_user="' . time() . '" where id="' . $id . '" and id_user=1';

$result1 = mysql_query($sqlquery1) or die(mysql_error() . ": Full Query was: " . $sqlquery1);

$result2 = mysql_query($sqlquery2) or die(mysql_error() . ": Full Query was: " . $sqlquery2);

if ( $result1 and $result2){
    ?><header class="major">
    Komen sukses! Kembali ke <a href="read_topic.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">Topik!</a>
</header>
<?php
}else{
    echo 'Terjadi kesalahan saat mengirim komen!';
}
?>
```

This will now also show you the query you tried to execute. This will help if you want further questions answered well.

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: The question was "anyone can help me ?" I helped him by supplying a way to self diagnose his problem.

Comment: Except that doesn't solve OP's problem. It's a suggestion to help him solve the problem, not a solution to the problem.